# Will the werewolf's Howl of Terror ability still be useful at higher levels?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I enjoy using the Beast Form ability to run into places like bandit dens and mauling all the bandits. When I do this, I continually use the Howl of Terror to make all hostiles cower, which makes it much easier for my werewolf to maul them all.

My question is will this strategy still work as my character progresses in level? I understand, through [this link](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lycanthropy_(Skyrim)#Werewolf_Powers), that by default the ability induces fear in enemies up to lv 25-30. However, [this link](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Werewolf), suggests that completing the Totems of Hircine quests will allow for the Howl of Terror to work against higher level enemies.

What I would like to know, regarding the Werewolf's Howl of Terror ability, is:

- Will it stop working as my level increases and enemies begin to scale to my higher level?
- If the answer to the above question is yes; is there a way that I can increase the strength of the ability so it works on higher level opponents?

  - Relating to this question, do the illusion perks [Aspect of Terror](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Aspect_of_Terror#Aspect_of_Terror) and [Kindred Mage](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kindred_Mage#Kindred_Mage) work with the Howl of Terror ability?

Answer (score 1):

Much a like the 'Dismay' shout and the Nord power (which i never used) the 'Howl of Terror' will have an effect throughout every level in the game.

Note that that the spell tome which also has this effect will later have no effect as you level up.

If you wish to boost smithing or any other skill i suggest you do this late on as your combat will be less effective throught higher levels when enemies get stronger. (DONT CHEAT) :)